# Determine if associated model attribute was updated Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, activemodel

How do I determine if an associated model attribute has been updated as `ActiveModel::Dirty` does not work on associated records? 
Say I have two models `RPS` and `Lawyer` with the following association:

```
class RPS < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :lawyers
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :lawyers, reject_if: lambda { |a| a[:email].blank? }, allow_destroy: true
end
```

Lawyers are optionally created through the RPS form as nested attributes. If a Lawyer is created two relevant values are saved: `:email` and `:rps_id`. 
If I then decide to update the lawyer (the email attribute) how can I determine if the email was changed as active model dirty does not work on associated records (`rps.lawyers.email_changed?`).

Comment: Are you asking from a testing standpoint?

Comment: @ruby_newbie no I'm not.

Comment: So then what are you trying to accomplish?  Are you just trying to have some type of callback functionality?  I just know that reaching into ActiveModel like that for control flow is generally not the best practice.  Can you explain on the high level what you want so I that I can see if there is a more "Rails-y" way to do it?

Comment: I am trying to trigger mailers through observers. If a user adds a lawyer  `after_create(rps)` is run in the RPS observer which triggers a mailer. If the user needs to update the lawyer email `after_update(rps)` is triggered which also has a mailer but this will also be run if any other attribute in the rps model is updated. So the observer needs to check if the lawyer email has changed and if so trigger the mailer. Otherwise the lawyer will receive an email every time an attribute in the rps is changed.

Comment: Why not just put the after_update on the lawyer instead?